# My browser lag because of this piece of code

Tags: javascript, html, api, loops, browser

I have a problem to fetch and add values from a weather API to my HTML elements.

I'm trying to forecast today from currently to midnight (the next day) and show the forecast hour by hour.

To gain space, I have used a while loop, but when I fetch the data, the browser doesn't work.

Here is an example of a JSON that I fetch : https://pastebin.com/ZjNh67Ni

Here is the code that mess up the browser :

```
for(let k = 0 ; k < value.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.length ; k++) {
                let l = k + 1;
                while(startHour + k < value.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.length) {
                    while(todayWeather.children[l] != undefined) {
                        todayWeather.children[l].children[0].innerHTML = new Date(value.forecast.forecastday[0].hour[startHour + k].time).getHours();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the structure of the HTML :

```
<div class="forecast-weather-box" id="today-h0">
   <h4 class="hour"></h4>
   <img src="" class="icon"/>
   <h4 class="temp-c"></h4>
</div>
```

Explaination line by line of the js :

I just will tell you what the variables are : so the var "value" is actually the JSON file. The var startHour is the round number of the current hour. And todayWeather is a big div that contains a lot of little divs like the HTML code above.

So first line, I create a loop that repeat itself 24 times (the number of hours).

I create a variable l that has one more number than k.

While the current hour + k is under 24,

While the child l of the big div is defined,

Then, I add a value to the first child of the child k, and I give the HTML the hour.

The l value has one more number than k because the first element of the big div (so 0 in the array) is just a title and not an other div.

I hope that I have been clear with my explainations. Thank you so much for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither `k` nor `l` are changing inside your while loop, so if the condition is true, it will stay true forever. Replace both whiles with if, or use a condition that changes between iterations.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! It's one of the first time that I've used "while" and don't remembered that it's a loop...